# how to qualify the index value must be the same as the id field of the corresponding property

Tags: typescript

Here is a type definition in TypeScript:

```
interface Obj {
id:string
}
```

I want to define a collection of Obj called ObjCollection, where the index of ObjCollection must be the same as the id field.

```
const objcollection: ObjCollection = {
  key1: { id: "key1" },
  key2: { id: "key2" },
  key3: { id: "key33333" } // Error, id should be key3
}
```

So how should ObjCollection be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific `ObjCollection` type in TypeScript that meets your requirement.  You can instead define a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like

```
type ObjCollection<K extends PropertyKey> =
    { [P in K]: { id: P } }
```

which expresses this idea, but it depends on supplying a type argument corresponding to a set of keys.  So your `objcollection` would be of type `ObjCollection<"key1" | "key2" | "key3">`.  To save you from having to write that yourself, you can write a generic helper function to have the compiler infer it:

```
const asObjCollection = <K extends PropertyKey>(
    oc: ObjCollection<K>) => oc;
```

Then instead of writing `const objcollection: ObjCollection = {⋯}`, you'd write `const objcollection = asObjCollection({⋯})`.  It's not the same, but it's pretty close, and it gives you the desired behavior:

```
const objcollection = asObjCollection({
    key1: { id: "key1" },
    key2: { id: "key2" },
    key3: { id: "key33333" } // error!
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAeQEYCsDCB7ANlmBjMASwwDsAeAaThgA8wYSATAZzgAUAnDWDyCmCAD44AXlBwJcAN5wA2mziEScCgF0AXNMWNNCgL5w9oPKWZg4AQ2bJ02XAWLKRcStToMW7Ljz4DBACnFJDDxNG0wcfCJSSkEASlFhEIBuUGNTcwxUE0iHUlFLa1QI+2iSfykgiQBrAQBGTRlCHTgAIlqIOtbDABoquA6AJkbtTXaBQe69PpBJAYEAZhHmsY6F9fWpuAB6bbgAUQ4uDh7tOGYACwwAVyxGOCR4NdA9ONSQUCA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I got a bit mixed up between the type system and the runtime values.